# Send data to api as map

Tags: flutter, api, http

hello i'm trying to send data contain [name,phone,password,password2,myphone ] as map

this's my login function it work just fine i want to make singup with the same logic

```
  login(Map body) async {
    var response = await api.post('url', body);

    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      var rawDara = json.decode(response.body);
      setToken(rawDara['token'].toString().trim());
      _status = Status.authenticated;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

i tried to loop in inside the map but i didn't work , when i click it didn't show any result or Problems
and the Sting show i only take nullable String

```
signUp(Map<String, String> userData) {
  String email = userData['name'];
  String password = userData['password'];
  String firstName = userData['password2'];
  String lastName = userData['phone'];
```

expected the data to be send to the api and i already write the error handler in the api file

```
 Future<http.Response> post(String url, Map body) async {
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(baseUrl + url), body: body);
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('Post On: $baseUrl$url \n with body: $body');
      print(
          'Status: ${response.statusCode} \n with response: ${response.body}');
    }
    return response;
  }
```

the post work just fine in the login

Comment: Have already you tried to use `Map<String, dynamic>` as type in signUp method?

Comment: yes i did try it but no data was send or error show

Comment: @AshGalmouz you want send data to `post()` method right?

Answer (score 1):

[you were using `HTTP` package flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/http).

in `HTTP` package when you get response , it will get in form of `String` so you convert it for getting actual Data (Response) like

```
 import 'dart:convert'; 
 final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
 print('result  -> $result '); // your api result
```

As same when you do `POST` request you mast have to pass(send) data in form of `String` only in `HTTP POST` Request

here way you can convert you `map` into `String`

```
final sendBody =  jsonEncode(body), // convert your body(map) into String
```

Now you can send sendBody(your map/body) in your `POST` request

```
 Future<http.Response> post(String url, Map<String,dynamic> body) async {
     try{
           Response response = await http.post(
                              Uri.parse(baseUrl + url), 
                              body: sendBody , // or use jsonEncode(body)
                             );
                             return response;
          } catch(e){
          print('error : $e'); 
    
      }
  }
```

Hope This will help you!